# I want to return HttpStatusCode along with Json Object from MVC Controller to javascript client

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have tried the following method, it is running fine locally but it returns only `BadRequest` without json object in response on the Testing server:

```
 var customObject = new { Message="", Parameters="a1,a2"};
 Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
 var responseData = new { ErrorCode = 1004, CustomObject = customObject };
 return result = Json(responseData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to return JSON data, your best solution is to use ASP.NET WebAPI.

The WebApi will return an `HttpResponseMessage` object which will contain the `HttpStatus` as well as the return data in Json format.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCustomer()
{
var customObject = new { Message="", Parameters="a1,a2"};
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, CustomObject = customObject);
}
```

You can easily convert your MVC Controller to an WebAPI controller by inheriting the class from `ApiController`, instead of `Controller` class.

Comment: Habeeb , i specifically needs the solution for MVC response not a web api  response